# Why can't I install this update (KB2597112)?

Tags: windows-update

A couple weeks ago a security update KB2597112 was released. Some of the computers were automatically updated. Most of the computers can't finish installation, because of an error:

> "The expected version of the product was not found on your system"

This update is quite important. The thing is, I am developing VBA applications for Word 2003. Update has installed itself automatically on my computer, without me even knowing about it, until users started reporting application failure on start. It seems that if I save the template on my updated computer, it won't work on computer wich does not have an update installed.

The problem is that this update is unreversable. If I would like to get rid off it, I would have to reinstall whole system, and even then, administrators can force this update on me.

On the other hand, installing update on users' computers should resolve this problem. That is the recommended solution (of course - installing security update must be a good thing...) Still, I can't do that, because of an error.

I downloaded update from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29389
Computers on wich problem occurs, have:
- Windows XP Proffesional SP3 
- Micorosoft Office Proffesional Edition 2003 with SP2 or SP3 (both not working).

Comment: Are you **positive** the machines in question have MSOffice 2003 SP3?  According to Microsoft "To install this security update, you must have Microsoft Office 2003 Service Pack 3 installed on the computer" so it's no wonder the ones with Office SP2 can't install the update.  You can get the latest Office service pack through here  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307841

Comment: Are you sure you selected the right language ?
IIRC that's the error you get when the language of the patch is different from your Windows installation.

Comment: I tried both - my language and english, both not working.
@Bon Gart, **I am positive** about SP3, I wouldn't say, there is one installed if there wasn't. Also, you provided a link to SP for Office XP.

Comment: My Apologies.  Here is a direct link to the Office 2003 SP3 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8 and I only mentioned making sure that they were SP3, because you said "Computers on wich problem occurs, have: - Windows XP Proffesional SP3 - Micorosoft Office Proffesional Edition 2003 with SP2 or SP3 (both not working)." which means you TRIED the update on machines with SP2, and that will fail since the update needs SP3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even thought in Word help I could see that SP3 is installed, only installing it one more time helped for that problem. I don't know if that was because some kind of failed installation or something...

Installing SP3 one more time is the solution.